Phone Pe Health Check - Error HTTP 406 Not Acceptable
I am trying to check the health of the PhonePe gateway, but I am getting error "HTTP 406 Not Acceptable":
{ code: 406, message: 'HTTP 406 Not Acceptable' }
I am using the following doc to integrate: https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/phonepe-pg-healthstatus


I explored and got the solution:
I am sending accept: text/plain in the header, this is wrong, I need to change accept: */* so that it can accept anything.
Update Header:
accept: */*

